# SQL Server : Check Constraint expression

Tags: check-constraints, mssql-jdbc

I have a check constraint in SQL Server that only allows 3 possible values, the expression is like this:

```
(([READ_WRITE] = 'H' OR [READ_WRITE] = 'W' OR [READ_WRITE] = 'R'))
```

I want to update this check constraint with a query because I don't have access to Management Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need to first drop the old check constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
    DROP CONSTRAINT CHK_YourTable_ReadWriteValues;
```

(and fill in whatever *actual* names you have for your table and the check constraint on it), and then you need to create the new one:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
    ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_YourTable_NewReadWriteValues
        CHECK ([READ_WRITE] IN ('X', 'Y', 'Z'));
```